# Format date using php

Tags: php

I have a PHP variable '$date', and it's value is: `y/m/d h:i:s` format.

**e.g:** $date = "2014-11-10 17:25:00";

I want to change this format to `m/d/y h:i:s` format, so that I'm using PHP code below. It's working fine but is there any PHP function to do it in one line of code ?

```
$date = "2014-11-10 17:25:00";
$explode = explode(" ", $date);
$part1 = $explode[0];
$part2 = $explode[1];
$explode = explode("-", $part1);
$year = $explode[0];
$month = $explode[1];
$day = $explode[2];
$created_date = "$month-$day-$year $part2";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date()` & `strtotime()` functions. Example:

```
$date = "2014-11-10 17:25:00";
echo date('m-d-Y H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

**Output:**

```
11-10-2014 17:25:00
```

Comment: Just Great. Exactly what I want.